# can't make mysql_query work

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Can't make this query work

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])){
  $id = $_GET['id'];

  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $id = (int)$id;
    $caption = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['caption']);

    mysql_query(" UPDATE  `photo_gallery`.`photograph` SET  `caption` ='{$caption}' WHERE  `photograph`.`id` ='{$id}' ");
```

but when I change it manually to this, it works

```
mysql_query("UPDATE  `photo_gallery`.`photograph` SET  `caption` =  'bruv' WHERE  `photograph`.`id` =3");
```

Comment: Put this in your code `$sql=" UPDATE photo_gallery.photograph SET  caption ='{$caption}' WHERE  photograph.id ='{$id}' ";` and then an `echo $sql;` and tell me what you see.

Comment: echo the evaluated string and look for the problem.

Comment: try to check the result: `if(!mysql_query('your query')) echo mysql_errno().': '.mysql_error();`

Comment: 'code' UPDATE photo_gallery.photograph SET caption ='' WHERE photograph.id =

Answer (score 0):

You have single quotes around {$id}. If your id's are hints in the database, then it shouldn't be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason for the curly braces in your SQL command? try this instead:

```
mysql_query(" UPDATE  `photo_gallery`.`photograph` SET  `caption` ='$caption' WHERE  `photograph`.`id` ='$id' ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mysql_query(" UPDATE  `photo_gallery`.`photograph` SET  `caption` ='".$caption."' WHERE  `photograph`.`id` = '".$id."' ");
```

Also use `intval` to parse int instread.

Answer (score 0):

the problem could be from mysql_real_escape_string. In the new version, the escaping is done by mysql and not by php anymore so .... for me it worked like this.

```
$caption = $_POST['caption'];

mysql_query(" UPDATE  `photo_gallery`.`photograph` SET  `caption` ='".mysql_real_escape_string($caption)."' WHERE  `photograph`.`id` ='".$id."' ");
```